# Need Help in choosing an API (Example: GOOGLE API) to find the nearest locations from my current location in India

Tags: google-maps

I am working on an Web App, if the user enters a given location (Ex: Street, Address, Country) it should bring all the retail locations which are nearer to the given location and the user should have the ability to click and view the map of the resulted retail locations and get the directions of the locations. I have done some research on Google Maps API, but i am not sure how efficient will Google Maps API will have the ability to provide Latitude and Longitude of any rural location in India.(The API should also work for Mobile devices(Android and Iphone etc.))
Is there any alternatives other than Google Maps API which will accomplish the above task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes far as I have known, Google Maps API is efficient when compared to any other API to find. Google Maps API had the information about all the Mandal Head Quarters in India, so does have the ability to provide Latitude and Longitude for any city's nearby.